# Display aside title if custom post type is related to course ID matching current course page ID

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

My current code below display the heading 'course instructors' at all times, when I need it to disappear when there are no course instructors.

What I need to happen is:

- Query all 'trainers' posts.
- Query the 'courses' field within each
  post.
- Check to see if the current course page ID exists within the
  'courses' field within any of the trainers posts.
- Display the
  trainers who have a course ID that matches the current course page
  ID.
- If any trainers has course ID that matches current course page ID then display heading 'Course Instructor'.

  ```
              <div class="instructors">

                  <?php
                  $trainersArray = array(
                      'post_type'      => 'trainers',
                      'posts_per_page' => -1,
                      'orderby' => 'name',
                      'order' => 'ASC'
                  );
                  query_posts($trainersArray);

                  $trainers = get_posts( $trainersArray );

                  ?>

                  <?php /*if($Course_ID):*/?>

                      <h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show -->

                  <?php /*endif;*/?>

                  <div id="trainers_list">
                      <?php

                      foreach ( $trainers as $trainer ) :

                          $trainerID = $trainer->ID;
                          $trainer_courses = get_field('courses',$trainerID);  //SELECT THE CONNECTED COURSE'S CUSTOM FIELD
                          $fullName = get_the_title($trainerID); //GET THE NAME FIELD IN TESTIMONIAL POSTS
                          $trainerPage = get_the_permalink($trainerID);
                          $feedback_count = 0;

                          if( $trainer_courses ):

                              foreach( $trainer_courses as $trainer_course ):

                                  $trainerCourseID = $trainer_course->ID;

                                  if ($trainerCourseID == $Course_ID) : ?>

                                      <div class="instructor-block">
                                          <div class="instructor-profile ">
                                              <div class="profile-name">
                                                  <?php echo $fullName; ?>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="profile-link">
                                                  <a href="<?php echo $trainerPage; ?>">
                                                      View Full Profile
                                                  </a>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div><br><!-- Another BR Fernando? and it's not even in body text, its after a DIV, whats your problem? -->
                                  <?php 
                                  endif;

                              endforeach; 

                          endif; 

                      endforeach; ?>  <!--echo json_encode( $trainers ); -->

                      <? wp_reset_query(); ?>

                  </div><!-- .trainers_list -->
              </div><!-- .instructors -->
  ```

Comment: That pesky Feranndo and is incessant use of break tags..

Comment: Anyway, whats you issuie - what isnt working, what did you expect instead

Comment: Tell me about it. At the moment the aside heading is displayed no matter what, i want it to only display if there are instructors related to the course.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the correct code? Maybe instead of creating a template part for this sidebar, Feranndo just coped and pasted this codeblock into every template that needs this sidebar, and you are editing the wrong template. Because if conditions are pretty simple, there is no way it can break (although the double nagative is weird `if(!$cond){//do nothing}else{//do something}` should be written `if($cond){//do something}`)

Comment: I am sure, as changes i make affect the output

Comment: I did try it the other way but it displayed the heading in both conditions.

Comment: I think the issue is using depreciated short tags. I added an answer that covers a few other issues though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120811/discussion-between-amesey-and-steve).

Comment: I think the issue might be that its checking to see if any trainers exist, not wether they are related to the course via the relationship field.

Comment: i've added more info about what I need above

Comment: OK, i see the issue. I will take a look at fixing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the logic that checks if this course has any trainers **before** you can perform any checks on the result.
Besides, moving you logic out of your html is a good idea.
Wordpress doesnt exactly make this easy, but the least we can do is perform the logic at the top of the file:

```
<?php
//lets get all our logic out of the html
$trainersArray = array(
    'post_type'      => 'trainers',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
query_posts($trainersArray);

$trainers = get_posts( $trainersArray );

//an array to hold any trainers for this specific course
$courseTrainers = [];

foreach ( $trainers as $trainer ) {

    $trainer_courses = get_field('courses',$trainer->ID);  //SELECT THE CONNECTED COURSE'S CUSTOM FIELD

    if(!$trainer_courses){
        continue; //no need to carry on this iteration
    }

    $fullName = get_the_title($trainer->ID); //GET THE NAME FIELD IN TESTIMONIAL POSTS
    $trainerPage = get_the_permalink($trainer->ID);

    foreach( $trainer_courses as $trainer_course ){
        //i presume $Course_ID is set elsewhere but is in scope?
        if($trainer_course->ID == $Course_ID){
            $courseTrainers[] = [
                'fullName'=>$fullName,
                'pageLink'=>$trainerPage
            ];
            break; //no further iterations needed
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
<div class="instructors">
    <?php if(count($courseTrainers)>0)://an empty array is falsey,but this is more explicit?>

        <h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show -->

    <?php endif;?>

    <div id="trainers_list">
        <?php foreach($courseTrainers as $trainer):?>
            <div class="instructor-block">
                <div class="instructor-profile ">
                    <div class="profile-name">
                        <?php echo $trainer['fullName']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile-link">
                        <a href="<?php echo $trainer['pageLink']; ?>">
                            View Full Profile
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- Your BR has been eradicated Feranndo - long live css ;-)-->
        <?php endforeach;?>

    </div><!-- .trainers_list -->
</div><!-- .instructors -->
```

What follows are some other issues spotted before the main issue became clear, but are still worth keeping in the answer:

1: You are using short open tags, that are depreciated and are probably the issue, change:

```
  <? if (!$trainers) { }else{?><h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show --><? } ?>
//^short tag                                                                                                                           ^another
```

to:

```
<?php if (!$trainers) { }else{?><h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show --><?php } ?>
```

2: the double negative is weird, change to

```
<?php if ($trainers){?><h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show --><?php } ?>
```

3: `$trainers` is not declared until after the check, so move that code up:

```
<?php 

    $trainersArray = array(
       'post_type'      => 'trainers',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'orderby' => 'name',
       'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    query_posts($trainersArray);

    $trainers = get_posts( $trainersArray );

?>
<div class="instructors">
    <?php if ($trainers){?><h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show --><?php } ?>
<div id="trainers_list">
    <?php                         
    foreach ( $trainers as $trainer ) {...
```

5: Finally, dont switch between `if():endif;` and `if(){}` syntax, its confusing. When working with html the former is prefered, so the final code becomes:

```
<div class="instructors">

    <?php
    $trainersArray = array(
        'post_type'      => 'trainers',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    query_posts($trainersArray);

    $trainers = get_posts( $trainersArray );
    ?>

    <?php if($trainers):?>

    <h3 id="trainers_heading">Course Instructors</h3><!-- only show this if there is instructors to show -->

    <?php endif;?>

    <div id="trainers_list">
        <?php

        foreach ( $trainers as $trainer ) :

            $trainerID = $trainer->ID;
            $trainer_courses = get_field('courses',$trainerID);  //SELECT THE CONNECTED COURSE'S CUSTOM FIELD
            $fullName = get_the_title($trainerID); //GET THE NAME FIELD IN TESTIMONIAL POSTS
            $trainerPage = get_the_permalink($trainerID);
            $feedback_count = 0;

            if( $trainer_courses ):

                foreach( $trainer_courses as $trainer_course ):

                    $trainerCourseID = $trainer_course->ID;

                    if ($trainerCourseID == $Course_ID) : ?>
                        <div class="instructor-block">
                            <div class="instructor-profile ">
                                <div class="profile-name">
                                    <?php echo $fullName; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile-link">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $trainerPage; ?>">
                                        View Full Profile
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br><!-- Another BR Feranndo? and it's not even in body text, its after a DIV, whats your problem? -->
                    <?php 
                    endif;

                endforeach; 

            endif; 

        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div><!-- .trainers_list -->
</div><!-- .instructors -->
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, but heading still displays under both conditions. Also I have short tags turned on for PHP, but i agree it should be '?php'..

Comment: I think the issue might be that its checking to see if any trainers exist, not wether they are related to the course via the relationship field.

Comment: i've added more info about what I need above

Comment: Just noticed the your comment after removing the '<br>' lol :)